# Selenium Chrome basic authentication secure method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chromedriver

I'm still new to automation and what i want to know if this method is secure in bypassing basic authentication, considering we are using https. By browsing i couldn't find any better practices of this case but i'm still not sure that it's secure and the best way:

```
driver.get("https://user:pass@whatever.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way is to encode credentials using Base64 encoding. 
[Yaron White's article](https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/997386) explains how it can be done using a custom key.